# warning: could not load any Objective-C class information after segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I am trying to use a custom segue in my ios app and when I preform the segue it always returns "warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available." as well as "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff504faff8)" which seems to be some kind of memory warning, but i'm not sure why.

This is the custom segue code, which seems to work in a blank project, but not in mine and I can't seem to find out what the above error means...

Has anyone seen this type of error before? (my searches on here have not returned anything that seems to be the same as what i'm seeing) - I've also included part of the stack trace below.

```
private func animateGrowScale() {
    let toViewController = destinationViewController
    let fromViewController = sourceViewController

    let containerView = fromViewController.view.superview
    let originalCenter = fromViewController.view.center

    toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)
    toViewController.view.center = originalCenter

    containerView?.addSubview(toViewController.view)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        toViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        }, completion: { finished in
            let fromVC = self.sourceViewController
            let toVC = self.destinationViewController
            fromVC.presentViewController(toVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
    * thread #1: tid = 0x1f0b0b, 0x000000011142e23e libobjc.A.dylib`objc::DenseMapBase<objc::DenseMap<DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> > >, DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> >, true>::find(DisguisedPtr<objc_object> const&) + 4, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff504faff8)
frame #0: 0x000000011142e23e libobjc.A.dylib`objc::DenseMapBase<objc::DenseMap<DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, true, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> > >, DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, unsigned long, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> >, true>::find(DisguisedPtr<objc_object> const&) + 4
frame #1: 0x000000011142c71d libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_tryRetain() + 75
frame #2: 0x000000011142bb75 libobjc.A.dylib`weak_read_no_lock + 99
frame #3: 0x000000011142c4c6 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_loadWeakRetained + 104
frame #4: 0x000000011142c4f2 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_loadWeak + 15
frame #5: 0x000000010fdb575e QuartzCore`CALayerGetContext + 47
frame #6: 0x000000010ff98461 UIKit`__windowForView + 103
frame #7: 0x0000000110089308 UIKit`-[UIViewController nextResponder] + 1002
frame #8: 0x000000011010323c UIKit`-[UIResponder _containedInAbsoluteResponderChain] + 24
frame #9: 0x0000000110103254 UIKit`-[UIResponder _containedInAbsoluteResponderChain] + 48
frame #10: 0x0000000110103254 UIKit`-[UIResponder _containedInAbsoluteResponderChain] + 48
frame #11: 0x000000010ffa77b3 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _containedInAbsoluteResponderChain] + 60
frame #12: 0x000000010ffa77b3 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _containedInAbsoluteResponderChain] + 60
frame #13: 0x000000010ffa77b3 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _containedInAbsoluteResponderChain] + 60
```

Comment: where do you set `sourceViewController` and `destinationViewController`?

Comment: Linked the two controllers in my main story board, and then override my prepareForSegue in the firstviewcontroller like below:

`override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue is CustomSegue {
            (segue as! CustomSegue).animationType = .GrowScale
        }
        
    }`

Comment: I've just run into a similar problem revisiting an old project, it now crashes with an infinite loop identical to your last 6 lines there, when showing an image picker for the camera view.

Comment: @theLastNightTrain i run into the same issue, with the image picker, did you solve the problem?

Comment: @aircraft v sorry, I only vaguely remember this now, I think it might have been something to do with how the image picker was presented, sorry I can't be more specific! (A guess is that I moved the presentation away from the local VC and made it present from window/rootVC maybe). HTH, good luck!

Comment: Hi @theLastNightTrain I get the same error when doing a presentViewController in the completion block of a custom segue animation.  I know it has been a while, but are you still doing it this way?  Meaning [UIView animateWithDuration: completion:] and doing the view animation in the animate block, then the sourceVC presentViewController:destinationVC in the completion block?  I get the same error so I'm trying to figure out the right way of doing custom animation ---> destinationVC.  All this is in perform() for me too.  Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be to call it on the main thread from your completion block, and have the destination VC call it. Otherwise sorry I'm not much help!